# Using auto layout constraint priorities to change the size of a view on different devices

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am using autolayout to create a UI. I am setting some constraints there.

[image]

In the above image, as you can see there, is a image view in the center. Now I want to set the size of the image view not proportional on iPad. I want to set its size slightly bigger than the iPhone 5, and in the center of the view. I want to use priorities here. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are multiple ways to apply constraint for this scenario. E.g. you have a width constraint of 90% to device width and another width constraint as max limit to width, let's say 400. So, constraint1 == 0.9*deviceWidth and constraint2 <= 400. Apply a priority of 1000 to second constraint and priority of 750 to first one.

Answer (score 3):

Hey you can use size classes for such kind of work. In iPad apply different constraint as you need.
Follow the below for complete reference to this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Comment: Size classes are time consumption work. Making two screen for one view so i don't like size classes

Comment: YEs but if such requirement come than you can use that. Another thing that you can do is you can programmatically check if the device is iPhone or iPad and change the constraints accordingly.

Comment: size classes shouldn't be any more work than using multiple constraints with priority. Simply select the size class in IB and turn the appropriate constraints on/off. Then do the next size class. You only have a single scene that adapts